# Py4JJavaError while trying to get data from Snowflake into Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, py4j

I am trying to get data from a Snowflake table into a Databricks spark dataframe. Here is my current code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.pandas as pypd
import pandas as pd
import re

options = {
  "sfUrl": sfURL,
  "sfUser": sfUser,
  "sfPassword": sfPassword,
  "sfDatabase": sfDatabase,
  "sfSchema": sfSchema,
  "sfWarehouse": sfWarehouse,
  "sfRole": sfRole
}

pydf = spark.read \
  .format("snowflake") \
  .options(**options) \
  .option("query", 
          $QUERY) \
  .load()
```

Everything up to this point loads just fine, but when I run `pydf.show()` to see the table, I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (ip-10-52-231-139.ec2.internal executor driver): net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Max retry reached for the download of #chunk0 (Total chunks: 2) retry=10, error=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Received close_notify during handshake.
```

And here is a truncated traceback:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-3910608059704003>, line 1
----> 1 pydf.show()

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:934, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    928     raise PySparkTypeError(
    929         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    930         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    931     )
    933 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 934     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    935 else:
    936     try:

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:188, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    186 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    187     try:
--> 188         return f(*a, **kw)
    189     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    190         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o710.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (ip-10-52-231-139.ec2.internal executor driver): net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Max retry reached for the download of #chunk0 (Total chunks: 2) retry=10, error=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Received close_notify during handshake.
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
...
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3578)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3510)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3499)
...
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Max retry reached for the download of #chunk0 (Total chunks: 2) retry=10, error=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Received close_notify during handshake.
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
...
```

My code worked fine three weeks ago, but all of a sudden it just stopped working. I am using i3.4xlarge, and I am using the Databricks runtime version "13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)", and it is unity catalog enabled and is using photon acceleration. I really, cannot tell what's going wrong here. Do I need to use a more updated compute, or a larger box?

Comment: Looks like the TLS handshake for downloading the resultset from Snowflake failed. What cloud provider is your Snowflake account on?

Comment: We are using AWS.

Comment: The error itself normally happens when there is a mismatch between SSL protocol version used by the client and the server. Are you sure there are no changes from your side (as in within your environment where Databricks is running)? This error is not related to the compute size. Are you able to connect with your browser to the Snowflake account and run the same query and see the resultset?

Comment: Yes I can do that, the query works fine in my snowflake worksheet. Yes, there have bee no changes from my side, I haven't changed the code at all. It sounds like I need to change my runtime version, do you know if one is guaranteed to work or is it on a case by case basis?

Comment: I don't think it's related to your code. Has the same compute worked before (with same runtime)? Maybe that is the cause. Maybe also try a version of Apache Spark that is marked as supported, 3.4,3.3 or 3.2 as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-install)

Comment: Do you think persisting or caching the dataframe will help ensure that it runs without error every time? I am using 3.4, and it ran successfully once but I can't get it to run again now...

Comment: How big was the DF you got first time vs what are you trying now? Caching is not going to solve the problem, especially if the underlying data in the table changes.

Comment: It was the same size, about 50k rows, three columns. Probably about 55 mb. Is that too much data? Should I try and query less?

Comment: No, that's fine. Strange that it worked once and then start giving you the error. If you have access to the Snowflake UI, I would check the Query History to see if the SELECT is actually run on the Snowflake side and it's only the resultset that can't be downloaded (since resultsets are cached and stored temporarily on the internal stage of the Snowflake account).

Comment: Yup, looking at my activity I can see my query, and then this second query `select * from table(result_scan('$STRING))`, and they both say SUCCESS

Comment: That means the issue is caused at retrieving the result set which usually is stored temporarily on the internal stage of the account. Run in Snowflake UI [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist) and check if the URL of the STAGE is reachable from your Databricks environment, as I believe that is the problem.

Comment: For checking to see if the URL is reachable, would I open up a web terminal and use `ping`? Or would I use a web scraping library?

Comment: A terminal with `curl` should be enough. But the idea is it should be from the same environment where your Databricks is to follow the same network path. If you have the possibility to install [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd) this tool would confirm for you.

Comment: Ok I tried `curl` but the connection timed out for my two STAGE urls, I don't think I'll be able to install SnowCD in Databricks but thank you for your help, I think I'll just manually download from snowflake and then upload to Databricks until the next update comes out

Comment: That means you have a network filter or a routing issue in the way. Rather than waiting for the next update, I would look to figure out why routing is not working.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to resolve the network filter or routing issue? Do you know where we should look? Do you know someone else I might talk to who has solved this issue before?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge on Databricks environments therefore I cannot tell you what exactly you should check. If your code worked before than I can only assume something changed in the environment. Do you know if you use Privatelink?